# Even if I have included all the dependencies in POM.xml, I am getting symbol not found error while "mvn install"

Tags: java, maven, rest-assured

I am new to maven. Please help!
Even if I have included all the dependencies in POM.xml, I am getting symbol not found error while "mvn install".

Here is the complete stack trace for your reference-

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Building XDMS Automation 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ XDMS ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ XDMS ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to C:\JavaProgs\xdms\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[7,22] package io.restassured does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[8,29] package io.restassured.config does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[10,30] package io.restassured.parsing does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[13,31] package io.restassured.response does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[14,31] package io.restassured.response does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[15,31] package io.restassured.response does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[17,29] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RestAssured
  location: package io.restassured
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[17,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[27,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[28,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[32,26] package org.testng.asserts does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[12,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[15,22] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RestAssured
  location: package io.restassured
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[21,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[23,1] package io.restassured.RestAssured does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[25,1] package org.hamcrest.Matchers does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[45,29] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ITestResult
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[151,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/resources/TestNGPagefactoryRunnerTest.java:[3,24] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/..../TestNGPagefactoryRunnerTest.java:[6,26] package cucumber.api.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/../TestNGPagefactoryRunnerTest.java:[9,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] /C:/.../CommonFunctions.java:[8,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/resources/StepDefCommon.java:[5,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/resources/StepDefCommon.java:[8,31] package io.restassured.response does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[44,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AfterMethod
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[59,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[69,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[82,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/.../SmokeTest.java:[104,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/.../SmokeTest.java:[119,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/.../SmokeTest.java:[135,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/.../SmokeTest.java:[156,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[166,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[184,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[207,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[236,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[244,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[252,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[269,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[276,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[283,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[304,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[43,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BeforeSuite
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[103,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[154,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable RestAssured
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[155,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[155,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[168,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[170,78] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable XmlConfig
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[170,47] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable RestAssured
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[168,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[179,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[179,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[189,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[196,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[211,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[213,92] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable XmlConfig
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[213,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable RestAssuredConfig
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[211,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[228,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[228,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[243,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[243,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[254,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[254,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[272,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[272,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[284,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[284,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[294,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[294,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method given()
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[304,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[306,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[INFO] 100 errors 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project XDMS: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[7,22] package io.restassured does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[8,29] package io.restassured.config does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[10,30] package io.restassured.parsing does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[13,31] package io.restassured.response does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[14,31] package io.restassured.response does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[15,31] package io.restassured.response does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[17,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class RestAssured
[ERROR] location: package io.restassured
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[17,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[27,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[28,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[29,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[31,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[32,26] package org.testng.asserts does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[12,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[13,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[14,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[15,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class RestAssured
[ERROR] location: package io.restassured
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[16,29] package io.restassured.config does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[17,29] package io.restassured.config does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[19,31] package io.restassured.response does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[21,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class RestAssured
[ERROR] location: package io.restassured
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[21,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[23,1] package io.restassured.RestAssured does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[24,1] package io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[25,1] package org.hamcrest.Matchers does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[45,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ITestResult
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[151,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[166,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[177,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[207,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[222,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[240,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[251,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[263,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[282,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[292,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[302,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[335,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[345,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[355,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[368,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[378,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/resources/TestNGPagefactoryRunnerTest.java:[3,24] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/resources/TestNGPagefactoryRunnerTest.java:[6,26] package cucumber.api.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/resources/TestNGPagefactoryRunnerTest.java:[9,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/CommonFunctions.java:[8,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/resources/StepDefCommon.java:[5,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/resources/StepDefCommon.java:[8,31] package io.restassured.response does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[44,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AfterMethod
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[59,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[69,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[82,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[104,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[119,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[135,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[156,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[166,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[184,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[207,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[236,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[244,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[252,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[269,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[276,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[283,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/SmokeTest.java:[304,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.SmokeTest
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[43,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BeforeSuite
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[103,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[103,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method given()
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[119,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[119,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method given()
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[154,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable RestAssured
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[155,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[155,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method given()
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[168,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[170,78] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable XmlConfig
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[170,47] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable RestAssured
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[168,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method given()
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[179,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Response
[ERROR] location: class restprograms.GrpUpdates
[ERROR] /C:/JavaProgs/xdms/src/restprograms/GrpUpdates.java:[179,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method given()
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Here is my POM.xml -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MyProject Automation</name>
  <description>MyProject Automation with Rest Assured</description>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

   <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/xml-path -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

  </dependencies> 
</project>
```

I am stuck with this since last week. Tried everything for the same error description on stackoverflow! Still no luck, hence posting the question.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You better follow standard Maven directory layout like `src/main/java`, `src/test/java` etc.

The problem in this case is probably that you're including

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

in test scope but use it in what appears to be "main" code.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this is to

1.Open POM.xml
2.Navigate to dependencies tab 
3.select rest assured click on properties button
4.In the scope field, change the value from test
    to compile.
5.Save it and run again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks "lexicore" for the suggestion. Even if I created the directory structure and copied files as per your suggestion, I was still getting error.

This error disappeared and I was able to run "maven install" through eclipse when I commented following line in POM.xml

```
  <build>
    <!-- <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> -->
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I commented out the scope test part of it,
since was using the standard Maven directory layout like src/main/java, src/test/java etc.